# cannot find type system.windows.controls.control in module system.windows.dll

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I converted a Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Store app.
All the changes went well, I was able to remove all the errors. 
Finally when I am trying to build my app I'm getting this error:

> "cannot find type system.windows.controls.control in module system.windows.dll" in the file C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v11.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets

Comment: please write the code, which throws such error.

Comment: i'm not able to find which part of the code is generating this error.. its saying in the file "Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets" on the line which only has this code "<CompileXaml"

Comment: Error is saying you are using `Control` which is not part of `system.windows.dll` of `WinRT`. In short the error is due to that control which is available for Windows Phone only.

Comment: thanks a lot.. i had "using Microsoft.Phone.Controls" in 5 files which was causing the problem.. build successful after removing those imports..

Comment: ok, I am posting my comment as answer. I would be glad if you please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: i'm very new to windows app development. if u can please guide me to some useful links from where i can learn the flow of application properly. Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store App both..

Comment: [31 Days of Windows 8](http://www.31daysofwindows8.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is saying you are using `Control` which is not part of `System.Windows.dll` of `WinRT`. In short the error is due to that control which is available for Windows Phone only.